# defining a function inside of a loop, value of i undefined or unpredictable

Tags: javascript, function, loops, closures

I would love some explanation of this (taken from javascriptkit.com):

```
function buildList(list) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var item = 'item' + list[i];
    result.push( function() {alert(item + ' ' + list[i])} );
  }
  return result;
}

function testList() {
  var fnlist = buildList([1,2,3]);
  // using j only to help prevent confusion - could use i
  for (var j = 0; j < fnlist.length; j++) {
    fnlist[j]();
  }
}
```

So `testList()` is pretty straightforward.
I tried following the first function step by step and this is what I figured it would return:

item 1 1
item 2 2
item 3 3

What I don't get is how `result` is returned as `item 3 undefined` 3 times - why undefined, and why only `item 3`?

-As I'm trying to learn, I'm not looking to get this to work, but rather understand what part I'm missing and why it doesn't come out as I would expect it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the problem?

The function in the for loop has a reference to `i` but `i` is changing in each iteration, so when you call the function declared in the loop it will use `i` with it's last value(3).

A simple closure will save the index value untouched:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    (function(index){
        var item = 'item' + list[index];  // why ?
        result.push( function() {alert(item + ' ' + list[index])} );    
    })(i);    
}
```

**Note:**

Why do you need `var item = 'item' + list[index];` if you re-lookup  the value in the list?

**Update** based on question  changed,

Because `i` has the final value- 3 which makes your code in the final iteration:

```
// i equals to 2 here
var item = 'item' + list[i]; // gives item3
result.push( function() {alert(item + ' ' + list[i])} );
// now `i` is changed to three so we don't enter the loop.
```

Values:

- `item` == `"item3"`
- `i == 3`
- `list[i]` == `list[3]` == `undefined`.

Comment: I think I saw this answered yesterday. Was it you? (`+1`)

Comment: Can you explain why the closure is needed?

Comment: I've updated the question, I might have no made it clear enough at first.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand that array returned by `buildList` contains `3` functions that share the same closure. Each time local variable of that closure is changed - it affects all functions that share it. In other words, `i`, `item` and `list` variables of all functions in result are the same. After loop has iterated through `list`, the value of `i` remains equal to `3` and it is true for all functions in `result` because they share reference to that variable. So, the answers to you questions will be like that:

**why undefined?**

Because `list[3] === undefined`

**why `item 3`?**

Because last time `item` variable was modified is when `i` was `2` and `for` executed its body (`list[2] === 3` therefore `item === 'item 3'`)